# Just opened an HTM file with the following code, is it dangerous?

Tags: javascript, security, malware, phishing

I received an email from an unknown person and opened an htm file in the attachment file. The following code executed :

```
<frameset onpageshow="document.location.replace(window.atob('aHR0cHM6Ly9tdXNrLmJ0Y2RvbmF0dmVyLnNpdGUvPzI0NDc1NTgg'));">
```

Did I just execute something that could harm my computer ?

Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: Exploits exists, so it's possible. Not a good stackoverflow question unless you share all the code that (may) have been executed. The above code just sends you to a different website.

Comment: okay thanks, that's the only line of code that was in the file

Comment: But probably not the only line of code on the website you got sent to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be dangerous to open email attachments received from untrusted sources, in general.

In your code, in particular, the following is happening:

- `window.atob` API is called to decode `aHR0cHM6Ly9tdXNrLmJ0Y2RvbmF0dmVyLnNpdGUvPzI0NDc1NTgg` base64 encoded string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob for the API reference.
- Using the free online base64 decoder (https://www.base64decode.org/ for example) you may translate `aHR0cHM6Ly9tdXNrLmJ0Y2RvbmF0dmVyLnNpdGUvPzI0NDc1NTgg` and get `https://musk.btcdonatver.site/?2447558` .
- On opening this page your browser may navigate to that URL, see `document.location.replace` API call
- Now, it depends on what `https://musk.btcdonatver.site/?2447558` is doing.

Please, do not open attachments from unknown people and untrusted sources.  They may contain malicious contents, phishing and content that may do damage otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, duly noted

Answer (score 1):

This sets the window location to

```
https://musk.btcdonatver.site/?2447558.
```

Looks like a scam but not sure. Possible wont do any harm unless you do something by visiting to that link.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think my ad blocker blocked the redirection since I did not end up on this website

Comment: It would be best not to actually provide a live link here.